# Не работает ctrl+/ и ctrl+shift+/ в Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublime-text, hotkeys

Linux. Sublime Text 3. Не могу закомментировать с помощью горячих клавиш <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> и <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>, остальные работают, а эти не хотят. Такая же проблема в Sublime Text 3 на Windows. Пробовал копировать строки из настроек в default в user, не помогает, в гугле ответов не нашел. Сбросил настройки, удалил плагины - не помогло. Полностью удалил, установил - не помогло. В чем может быть причина? Переназначил на другие клавиши - все работает. В системных гор. клавишах данной комбинации не нашел.

Comment: Не пробовали язык клавиатуры поменять? У меня в PyCharm  групповое комментирование на русском не работает

Comment: Ramil, данные горячие клавиши не работают у Вас в любых файлах с любым синтаксисом или в каких-то отдельных файлах? Спасибо.

Comment: @danilshik, в Sublime Text подобной проблемы не должно быть. Вероятные причины: // **1.** Хоткеи автора используются другой программой, // **2.** Баг конкретных синтаксисов — я сталкивался с этой проблемой в некоторых. // Чтобы определить проблему точно, пока информации для меня недостаточно, подожду ответа. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

я и на [тостере](https://toster.ru/q/519907?utm_source=email_notifications&utm_medium=email&utm_content=new_answer&utm_campaign=notifications#answer_1200488) поднимал этот вопрос, сам ответил:

> пол дня потратил на поиск решения, все облазил вдоль и поперек, оказалось все проще - ctrl + / или ctrl + shift + / - здесь слэш я нажимал который находиться на цифровой клавиатуре справа (над циферками), а нужно нажимать слэш находящийся возле клавиши enter (случайно нажал) и все работает, или я дурак или лыжи не едут :) я в шоке!

Это баг в sublime-text или это нормально? На обеих клавишах одинаковый слэш, а результат разный.

Comment: Такое поведение во всех мне известных программах. Если вводите символ, то поведение `/` и `keypad_divide` одинаково, обе клавиши вводят символ со сканкодом `(0x2f)`. Но в составе шорткатов клавиши будут иметь разный смысл `ctrl+/` и [**`ctrl+keypad_divide`**](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/key_bindings.html#bindable-keys). То же самое в других программах в случаях, когда один и тот же символ на разных клавишах. Спасибо.

Comment: в других программах такого не замечал, возможно потому что шорткаты были настроены на / цифровой клавы, поэтому по привычке нажимал эту комбинацию, но теперь буду знать. Всем спасибо.